# Converting a WSP to WAP, generated xsd .designer files not compiling

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vs-web-site-project, vs-web-application-project

I am converting an old WSP (VB) to a WAP, I have already converted it from .net 2 to .net 4 and it ran perfectly and I had no issues
sadly, when I converted from a WSP to a WAP, the app_code folder moved over fine, but when I copied the remaining bits over and ran the convert to WAP, all the xsd files generated a .designer file, and none of these are compiling at all, throwing hundreds of errors.. such as:

```
Public Overloads Sub AddFooRow(row As FooRow)' has multiple definitions with identical signatures.  
Attribute 'XmlSchemaProviderAttribute' cannot be applied multiple times.    
Public Sub New()' has multiple definitions with identical signatures.   
Public ReadOnly Property SELLColumn As System.Data.DataColumn' has multiple definitions with identical signatures.
```

I was following this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/10/29/converting-a-web-site-project-to-a-web-application-project.aspx

it also seems that as some of these xsd's were in the App_code folder in the WSP that as part of the conversion, they are moved into the root of the new WAP,

has anyone successfully managed to do a conversion like this?
any help much appreciated

thanks